# Arithmetic operations on list with missing values

Tags: list, scala, math, missing-data

I'm trying to do some arithmetic on a list that may contain missing values.
So far, I'm representing my list with Option[Int]:

```
val mylist=List( Option(4), Option(8), None )
```

With this representation, I can easily apply a function over the list (say, multiply by 2):

```
scala> mylist.map(_.map(_*2))
res2: List[Option[Int]] = List(Some(8), Some(16), None)
```

However, this looks more complicated than it needs be, so I'm wondering if I'm missing something.

Also, I can't figure out how to write things like the sum. I guess it should be possible with a (big) reduce expression...

So, I'd like to know if:

- List[Option[Int]] is a good representation for this use case
- `mylist.map(_.map(_*2))` is the best way to map
- is there a simple way to do a sum?

Comment: To sum values you can go with `mylist.flatten.sum`

Comment: Someone down voted all the answers

Comment: @drstevens incident reported

Comment: @drstevens and om-nom-nom: I'm curious, why would anyone do so? (unless they downvote all answers but *their own*?)

Comment: @scala_newbie I have no idea why. As of this morning, all answers were -1 with two exceptions, one of which was zero because I had previously up-voted it. Apparently all answers have since been upvoted once except mine. I didn't notice it first either. See  phant0m's comment on Kim Stebel's answer.

Comment: @drstevens That's strange. I've been upvoting here indeed, but I didn't downvote anything ever, yet

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's not a pattern I've used myself, but if values can be "missing" then an `Option` is appropriate. But a `List` probably isn't. In a `List` the position isn't usually something you should be relying on, since it's not random-access. Maybe a `Vector` would be better, or you need to think of a better way of modelling your problem, i.e. not as a list with missing values.

You can deal with `Option` nicely using for-expressions:

```
for (o <- mylist; x <- o) yield x * 2
```

or flatten the list:

```
mylist.flatten.map(_ * 2)
```

To sum it:

```
mylist.flatten.sum
```

Comment: For comprehension and flattening doesn't persist Nones, and looks like @scala_newbie wanted to save them. If not, there is also one more way: flatMap them: `mylist.flatMap(_ * 2)`

Comment: actually @om-nom-nom, flatMapping doesn't work (I had the same idea), since the function's parameter type has to be `Option[Int]`

Answer (score 1):

> - List[Option[Int]] is a good representation for this use case

Is it possible to flatten it earlier with flatMap? For example, if you are creating this list using map, you could use flatMap instead and not have missing values. My suggestion is to not even represent the missing values if possible. If you need to represent them, Option is ideal.

> - `mylist.map(_.map(_*2))` is the best way to map
> - is there a simple way to do a sum?

The nested map is probably preferable. You can `foldLeft` also.

`foldLeft` is also helpful if you need to do something besides sum/product.

```
scala> val mylist=List( Option(4), Option(8), None )
mylist: List[Option[Int]] = List(Some(4), Some(8), None)

scala> mylist.foldLeft(0){
     |   case (acc, Some(i)) => acc + i 
     |   case (acc, _) => acc
     | }
res7: Int = 12

scala> (0 /: mylist) {
     |   case (acc, Some(i)) => acc + i 
     |   case (acc, _) => acc
     | }
res8: Int = 12

scala> (0 /: mylist) {
     |   case (acc, Some(i)) => acc - (i * 2)
     |   case (acc, _) => acc
     | }
res16: Int = -24
```

Answer (score 0):

> So, I'd like to know if:
>
> List[Option[Int]] is a good representation for this use case

Option is definitely the preferable way to express missing values. You could also think about changing it into a `List[(Int, Int)]` where the first element indicates the position in your original list and the second element represents the value.

> `mylist.map(_.map(_*2))` is the best way to map

In my opinion there is no shorter or cleaner way to express that. (You have two "levels" that's why you need two maps!) With my suggested data structure this would turn into `mylist.map(t => (t._1, t._2*2))`.

> is there a simple way to do a sum?

No easier way than om-nom-nom suggested. With my data structure it would be `mylist.map(_._2).sum`

Answer (score 0):

The most general and most concise way to do this is with [Scalaz](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/)'s semigroup type class. That way, you're not restricted to `List[Option[Int]]` but can apply the same function to `List[Int]`.

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

object S {
  def double[A:Semigroup](l:List[A]) = l.map(x => x |+| x)
  def sum[A:Semigroup](l:List[A]) = l.reduce(_ |+| _)

  def main(a:Array[String]) {
    val l = List(Some(1), None, Some(2))
    val l2 = List(1,2)
    println(double(l))
    println(sum(l))
    println(double(l2))
    println(sum(l2))
  }

}
```

This prints

```
List(Some(2), None, Some(4))
Some(3)
List(2, 4)
3
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure what it is you are trying to achieve, but this does'nt seem like the right approach. if you need to determine if a value exists in your "list", then perhapse a `Set` would suit your needs better:

```
scala> val s = Set(4,8)
s: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(4, 8)

scala> s(4)
res0: Boolean = true

scala> s(5)
res1: Boolean = false

scala> s map (_ * 2)
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(8, 16)

scala> s reduceLeft((a,b) => a+b)
res3: Int = 12
```

or even easier:

```
scala> s sum
res4: Int = 12
```

if you need something more sophisticated, and the index of the element in your list is important, you may use a `Map` where the keys simulate the index, and missing values can be mapped to some default value:

```
scala> val m = Map(1 -> 4, 2 -> 8) withDefault(n => 0)
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 4, 2 -> 8)

scala> m(1)
res5: Int = 4

scala> m(3)
res6: Int = 0

scala> m map {case (k,v) => (k,2*v)}
res7: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 8, 2 -> 16)

scala> m.foldLeft(0){case (sum,(_,v)) => sum+v}
res8: Int = 12
```

again, not sure what your needs are, but it feels like you are going the wrong way...
`Option` is a type i would think twice before using. ask yourself if it's realy necessary. there might be solutions that would achieve what you are trying to do in a more elegant way.

Comment: In my use case, I have a Seq of objects. I need to compile statistics on attributes of those objects, but these objects have (different) missing attributes. I'm not sure how I'd use those techniques here

Comment: how 'bout using a `Map[YourObjects,List[Attributes]]`?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your suggestion. How would I store my attributes in a **list** without Option? And if you're suggesting to only keep a list of *existent* attributes, how would I tell them apart (their indexes won't be fixed)?

Comment: i am suggesting to only keep a list of _existent attributes_. lets say you have an attribute trait: `MyAttribute`, then, for every needed attribute you can extend the trait to a real value. like: `SomeAttribute <: MyAttribute` & `AnotherAttribute <: MyAttribute` etc'... well, you could then have your map like i suggested with `List[MyAttribute]` (attribute indexes could be retrieved through an abstract method in the `MyAttribute` trait)

Comment: alternatively, if the attributes are realy simple, and creating a super trait is an "overkill solution", you could use: `Map[YourObject,Map[Int,Attribute]]`